# How to fix ModuleNotFound?

Tags: python, django

It was all working when i started the server first time without startapp.
after i made an application and did some modifications in the application now the server is not starting.

they only changes I made in views.py and urls.py

```
Here is the log.

PS E:\CS50\files\Django\demo> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Basit Khan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hellodjango'
```

*** default urls.py ***

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('hello/', include("hello.urls")),
    ]
```

***my application urls.py ***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")
]
```

***views.py***

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world")
```

*** the only added 1 line in settings, the first one ***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'hello'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you need add `hellodjango` in your `settings.py` in APP section

**UPDATE**

in your error log app name is `hellodjango`, but in installed app just `hello`